# Are there any perks dependent on your squad leader?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Does having a specific blade as your squad leader in mercenaries missions have any effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only effect that the squad leader has is the name of the squad. There are a few missions that will require a specific squad leader but outside of that and the name, the leader does not have an effect on the mission.